# Como deshabilitar SSL desde JAVA en MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-workbench, ssl

Cada vez que tengo una conexión con mi base de datos me aparece el siguiente mensaje:
`You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.`

He visto maneras de deshabilitar pero ninguno coincide con la estructura de mi conexión, que es:
`Connection conex = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/comercial", "root", "");`

Con esta estructura de conexión como podría deshabilitarla?. Ya que varios dicen escribir al final **useSSL = false** de la siguiente manera: `Connection conex = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/comercial?useSSL=false", "root", "");`, pero me lanza el mismo mensaje de advertencia.

O me recomiendan cambiar directamente la estructura de mi conexión?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, incluye en tu pregunta explícitamente cómo fue que intentaste usar useSSL y qué error encontraste. "No me funciona" es una descripción pobre.

Comment: Para añadir parámetros directamente en la cadena de conexión tendrías que usar `?`  y a partir de ahí pones los parámetros asociados por el nombre específico del mismo y el valor, por ejemplo: **`Connection conex = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/comercial?useSSL=false", "root", "");`**  En caso de necesitar pasar varios parámetros, tendrías que usar `&` para separar cada uno, algo así más o menos: `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/comercial?useSSL=false&otraLlave=otroParametro"`. Ahora te toca decidir, según el mensaje, si te conectarás sin SSL o indicas el certificado.

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias por la recomendación, ya hice nuevamente la edición de mi pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano estuve probando de esa manera `Connection conex = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/comercial?userSSL=false", "root", "");` pero sigue apareciendo el mensaje de advertencia.